# Unexpected token 004 at position 0 when posting JSON object in C

Tags: c, json, curl, json-c

Im having a problem when trying to send a JSON object that I created in C. The server is able to both send and receive data just fine. Im quite an amateur when it comes to C.

```
    static int main_curl(neardal_record* pRecord)
    {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    char * record = pRecord->representation;

    json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object(); 
    json_object *jstring = json_object_new_string(record);

    json_object_object_add(jobj,"id", jstring);


    curl = curl_easy_init();

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charset: utf-8");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.43.20:5000/api/swipes");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jobj);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcrp/0.1");
    printf ("The json object created:%s ",json_object_to_json_string(jobj));


    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return res;
    }
```

When printing out the JSON object im getting this ->
    `The json object created:{ "id": "hello, world" }`

The server response is as follows

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse 
    (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at createStrictSyntaxError 
    (/Users/backend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)<br> 
    &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (/Users/backend/node_modules/body- 
    parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at 
    /Users/backend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; 
    &nbsp;at invokeCallback (/Users/backend/node_modules/raw- 
    body/index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done 
    (/Users/backend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; 
    &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/backend/node_modules/raw- 
    body/index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:333:22)<br> &nbsp; 
    &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at 
    processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)</pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When intercepting the request with Wireshark the Post looks like this
[POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyMAZ.png)
And the response error is this
[BAD REQUEST 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLg9r.png)

Im almost certain that the error is the way i'm building my JSON object, but as aforementioned I am very new at C. If I hardcode a text instead of the object the request is a success. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out after all by changing this
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jobj);`
to this
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_object_to_json_string(jobj));`

correct me if im wrong but im assuming that I cannot just send a JSON object without turning it into a String first.

Any further suggestions would be appreciated!